# Nginx - get subdomain as variable

Tags: nginx, subdomain, config

I have a couple of subdomains with the same behavior (based on subdomain name) and I am trying to find the best solution with less overhead for the nginx server.
On that domain there are also default www and non-www domains, also a wildcard (those "couple of" subdomains should not match the wildcard).

So far I've found 3 possible solutions:

1. define each subdomain in separate server block, and hardcode the subdomain

   ```
   server {
       server_name one.domain;
       # config with "one"
   }
   server {
       server_name two.domain;
       # same config with "two"
   }
   ... three, four etc.
   ```

this should be ok, but it's not DRY (don't repeat yourself)
also it's long and looks ugly

2. catch server_name in a regexp

   ```
   server {
       server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>one|two|three|...)\.domain\.com$;
       # config with $subdomain
   }
   ```

config is cleaner, but there is a regexp overhead, also may interact with the wildcard virtual host, I'm not sure which will take precedence

3. static hostname plus map

   ```
   server {
       server_name one.domain two.domain three.domain ....;
       # config with $subdomain, where $subdomain is a map based on $server_name, extracting all characters before .
   }
   ```

this should be the best approach, vhost selection is based on string compare (no regexp), but I still have regexp usage in that "map"

The question is: can the third solution be improved ?

As in extracting part of a string (i.e. $subdomain from $server_name) without using a regexp ?

All subdomains are on the same level, and all end in .domain

Comment: [This document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) may help. Also, you could use [`include`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: read it already, also read many articles, but didn't find the perfect solution; indeed, include may help, but still there will be N server blocks instead of single one; also an IF may help, but it will be the same as a map, just more 'evil' :-P